# Remove cells from word table with Novacode DocX

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

How do I remove a single cell from a word table using Novacode DocX?

I have tried:

```
table.Rows[0].Cells.RemoveAt(2);
```

and

```
Cell c = table.Rows[0].Cells[2];
table.Rows[0].Cells.Remove(c);
```

and

```
table.Rows[0].Cells.RemoveRange(2,4);
```

None of them remove any cells.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with Novacode DocX very recently. Something I have realized is that a lot of the methods classes have are inherited and are not overridden. An example is `cell` inherits `Remove()` from `container` and is never overridden to do what you would expect it to do.
[sorcecode for Novacode.Table](https://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DocX/Table.cs)

What you can do to try and get around this is to hide the cell/cells, since I am assuming you are not removing an entire row or column.

```
Novacode.Table table = document.Tables[0]
Novacode.Row row = table.Rows[0]; //int of row that contains cell/cells to remove
int first_cell = 0; //beginning cell of range
int last_cell = 1; //last cell of range
for(int i = first_cell; i < last_cell + 1; i++)
{
    foreach (var paragraph in row.Cells[i].Paragraphs)
    {
        paragraph.Remove(false);
    }
}
row.MergeCells(first_cell, last_cell);
Novacode.Cell cell = row.Cells[first_cell];
Novacode.Border border = new Border();
border.Tcbs = Novacode.BorderStyle.Tcbs_none;
cell.SetBorder(Novacode.TableCellBorderType.Right, border);
cell.SetBorder(Novacode.TableCellBorderType.Left, border);
cell.SetBorder(Novacode.TableCellBorderType.Top, border);
cell.SetBorder(Novacode.TableCellBorderType.Bottom, border);
```

This code would remove text and merge the first two cells of your first table and make there borders invisible. So this would turn the area you want deleted into one invisible blank cell, assuming you are using `Paragraphs` of text in the `Cell`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to save the table back to the document.
Try

1. appending the table to the end of the document. if that's missing the cells
2. Remove and replace the table in the document.

Comment: I tried appending the table at the end of the document, and it still has the cells I'm trying to delete :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the child XML from the Cell Element yourself, as it is not correctly handled by the NovaCode DocX Api:

```
table.Rows.Last().Cells.Last().Xml.RemoveAll();
table.Rows.Last().Cells.Last().InsertParagraph();
```

Note that the InsertParagraph in the end is necessary as Cells cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Table` class you can use the methods

```
MergeCells(int, int)
```

and

```
MergeCellsInColumn(int, int, int)
```

to 'remove' cells.

See: https://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DocX/Table.cs